# Upgrade experience from EF6 to EF7 (aka EF Core 1.0)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Can anyone share their experience and insights on upgrading from EF6 to EF7?
Was it straight forward? Did you discover any major benefits or drawbacks from this upgrade?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this Side-by-side comparison between EF-6 and EF Core 1.0. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features

if you need any feature which is still not done then use EF 6 because maybe you have to wait a long time.

My recommendation, if it is really not possible to use EF 6 because you have .NET Core on UWP etc, then use it, otherwise ***currently*** you can prefer to use EF 6 over EF Core this is also a recommendation from EF team you can find it on the Announcing Entity Framework Core 1.0.

**When to use EF Core**

**We now have a Comparing EF Core and EF6.x section in our documentation. It includes guidance on when to use EF Core, feature comparisons, and information on porting to EF Core.**

These are the types of applications we would recommend using EF Core for. For all other applications, you should consider using EF6.x.

- New applications that do not require features that are not yet implemented in EF Core.
- Applications that target .NET Core, such as Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and ASP.NET Core applications.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/entity-framework-core-1-0-0-available/

Comment: I believe the link is now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/index

Comment: @Koder, Thank you :-)

Comment: Just for clarifiation: `EF7 = EF Core 1.0`